# Constraint not being created in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried creating a table using the below query

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
  cust_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  cname VARCHAR(255),
  CONSTRAINT pk_customer PRIMARY KEY (cust_id));
```

The table got created successfully with cust_id as the primary key. But if I try to drop the constraint pk_customer using the below query

```
   ALTER TABLE customer
   DROP CONSTRAINT pk_customer;
```

I am getting an error that says:

> Error Code: 3940. Constraint 'pk_customer' does not exist.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Primary key constraint in MySQL **always** has pre-defined name `PRIMARY`. If you specify some another name it will be ignored.

Comment: @Akina thank you that helped

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to drop a primary key in MySQL is this:

```sql
ALTER TABLE customer DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```

However, using this on the exact table definition you gave above will then generate this error:

> Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Had you made the primary key a non auto increment column, the above `ALTER TABLE` statement would have worked:

```sql
CREATE TABLE customer (
    cust_id INT NOT NULL,
    cname VARCHAR(255),
    CONSTRAINT pk_customer PRIMARY KEY (cust_id)
);

ALTER TABLE customer DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```